# How to know the integer primary key of recently added row in python sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, key

Suppose I have 2 tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE forms (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    form_name TEXT, 
 )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE formsData (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    formid INTEGER,
    data TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(formid) REFERENCES forms(id)
 )
```

I have inserted some datas in forms table:

```
INSERT INTO forms(form_name) VALUES ('form1')
INSERT INTO forms(form_name) VALUES ('form2')
```

Now I want to add some data in second table formsData as:

```
INSERT INTO formsData(formid,data) VALUES ('XXXXXXXX','data for form1')
INSERT INTO formsData(formid,data) VALUES ('XXXXXXXX','data for form2')
```

My problem is to find the XXXXXXXX which is the foreign key with the id field of forms table.  Is there any way to get this id from forms table to be added in formsData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function to refer to the row id (primary key) of a previous insert. You'll need to reorder the inserts, of course:

```
INSERT INTO forms(form_name) VALUES ('form1');
INSERT INTO formsData(formid,data) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(),'data for form1');
INSERT INTO forms(form_name) VALUES ('form2');
INSERT INTO formsData(formid,data) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(),'data for form2');
```

Comment: Ah, of course, I missed that detail. I hear the caffeine supply machine calling me!